# Go variables escape to the heap when using the add operator to concatenate strings

Tags: go, memory-management, stack, heap-memory, escape-analysis

Question about this code . why variables escape to heap

```golang
func main() {
    port := "8080"
    host := "localhost:"
    connection := host + port
    fmt.Println(connection)
}
```

gorun -gcflags "-m -l" main.go

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:12:21: host + port escapes to heap
./main.go:13:13: ... argument does not escape
./main.go:13:13: connection escapes to heap
```

And I found if use `fmt.Sprintf` it also cause the variables escape to heap

Comment: This is an implementation detail. Other compilers or compiler versions might not use the heap here.

Answer (score 4):

It's not the concatenation but the call to the `fmt` package that causes the escape.

If you call the builtin `println()` function instead, it won't:

```
println(connection)
```

Running `go run -gcflags "-m -l" main.go`:

```
# command-line-arguments
./main.go:12:21: host + port does not escape
localhost:8080
```

In case of `fmt.Println()` the compiler can't guarantee what will happen to the passed value, so it puts it on the heap.

Comment: Thanks for explain. so use the strings.builder will be better than use fmt.Sprintf right? If join many string.. I must write many `sb.WriteString` then `sb.String()`.Do you have a good way ?

Comment: Yeah, usually `strings.Builder()` is faster @xiaodonghuan, since it avoids memory allocations. The easiest way to know for sure is to write a benchmark and run it with `-benchmem`.

Comment: Yes `strings.Builder()` is faster; but for such small operations, I don't think it's really going to perform better. So don't lose the readability of the code for such tiny improvements (or maybe not). Rule of thumb: Do benchmarks!